# Attempting to use Nightmare .type() with an element only obtainable by name

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I am attempting to use nightmare js to submit a form via typing into an element and then clicking the submit button.

However, the text boxes do not have element IDs only element Names
I have tried using

```
document.getElementsByName()
```

But I am unsure how to use this in conjunction with

```
.type()
```

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand selectors a bit more now,

```
input[name="elementName"]
```

works where input is the title of the element